# XML (multiple level) to HTML conversion using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML

```
<Tickets><Ticket><id>9590355</id><manager>ABC</manager>
<Row><Account>Account 1</Account><Price>8</Price></Row>
<Row><Account>Account 2</Account><Price>3</Price></Row>
</Ticket></Tickets>
```

I want to convert this XML into HTML with this final result (2 tables, one table for the Ticket, another table below is for the Row):

```
id      manager
9590355     ABC

Account     Price   
Account 1   8   
Account 2   3
```

When I use the below XSLT, it didn't show the data from Row.

```
<xsl:template match="Tickets">
<p style='width:100%;text-align:center;'>
  <table align='center' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='560'>
    <tr style='width:100%;background-color:#3e608e;color:white;height:20px;font-weight:bold;'>
      <td style='width:35px;'>id</td>
      <td style='width:110px;padding-left:1px;'>manager</td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Ticket" />
  </table>    
</p>
<p></p>
<p style='width:100%;text-align:center;'>
<table align='center' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='560'>
  <tr style='width:100%;background-color:#3e608e;color:white;height:20px;font-weight:bold;'>
    <td style='width:35px;'>Account</td>
    <td style='width:110px;padding-left:1px;'>Price</td>
  </tr>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Row" />
  </table>
</p>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="Ticket">
<tr style='width:100%;background-color:white;color:#333333;'>
  <td style='width:35px;padding-left:1px;'>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="id"/>
  </td>
  <td style='width:110px;padding-left:1px;'>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="manager"/>
  </td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="id">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="manager">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row">
  <tr style='width:100%;background-color:white;color:#333333;'>
    <td style='width:140px;padding-left:1px;'>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Account"/>
    </td>
    <td style='width:140px;padding-left:1px;'>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Price"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Account">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Price">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the result from the above xslt (notice there is no Row data under Account and Price columns)

```
id      manager
9590355     ABC

Account     Price
```

How can I fix this XSLT to show the Row data under Account and Price columns ?

Answer (score 0):

In stead of:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Row" />
```

Use:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Ticket/Row" />
```

Why?
This `apply-templates` is inside a template match `Tickets`.

If we have a look at your xml:

```
<Tickets>
  <Ticket>
    <id>9590355</id>
    <manager>ABC</manager>
    <Row>
      <Account>Account 1</Account>
      <Price>8</Price>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Account>Account 2</Account>
      <Price>3</Price>
    </Row>
  </Ticket>
</Tickets>
```

`Row` is not a Child of `Tickets` but of `Ticket`
You could compare it with being in  a directory structure and trying to navigate from directory `Tickets` to `Row`.
You would have to use something like cd `Ticket/Row` to get to the `Row`.

It is the same with xslt. You always have context. And inside a match template that is your context is: your are inside the matched element. (Until you would use a for-each for example. Than inside the for-each, your context also changes)

Comment: Does this answers your question?